# Could not load type 'Azure.Messaging.MessageContent' from assembly 'Azure.Core'

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, appinsights, queuetrigger

I have an azure functions queue trigger. It's working fine locally but not when deployed. In Application Insights I could see the below error message & the queue trigger won't get invoked because of this exception. I had a .netcore 3.1 app with azure functions v3. Even I upgraded it to .net6.0 & azure functions v4. Also, I tried upgrading, downgrading & installing some packages still it didn't resolve the issue.

[image: Error message]

How to fix System.TypeLoadException - Could not load type Azure.Messaging.MessageContent from assembly Azure.Core?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your deployed FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION matches what's in your function's csproj or it may try to look for packages that are not available on the App Service you've deployed. (See: [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/set-runtime-version?tabs=portal))

Comment: Yes it has the same version as the csproj file.